# How to create sub folder using user's userID in main folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

I am currently one issue - which is to create a sub folder (which is named after each user's ID name). Following is what I had tried.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

    if (filepath.ToLower() != ".pdf" && 
        filepath.ToLower() != ".png" && 
        filepath.ToLower() != ".gif" &&
        filepath.ToLower() != ".zip")
    {
        lblmessage.Text = "Only pdf, png and gif file are accepted";
    }
    else
    {
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 5000000)
        {
            lblmessage.Text = "Maximum size (5MB) exceeded";
        }
    }

    foreach (HttpPostedFile postedfile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(filepath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath);
        }

        string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedfile.FileName);
        postedfile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Courses/FAID_CSP/ADMIN_NO/" + filename));
    }

    lblmessage.Text = string.Format("{0} Selected Files Are Submitted into DB", 
        FileUpload1.PostedFiles.Count);
}
```

}

Comment: what's the issue you are facing?

Comment: Hi Chetan. I am unable to create a sub folder which I want to name after the user's user ID. Currently this is my folder flow: Courses/FAID_CSP_ADMIN_NO.

Comment: `if (!Directory.Exists(filepath))` This seems strange - isn't `filepath` actually the file extension?

Comment: Hi Rufus. I do not have any error or exception. It's just that whenever I select a file to upload, it always store in the "ADMIN_NO" folder. Which is not I wanted. What I want is to store into a specific user folder (e.g. 2020ABC)

Comment: You have `"ADMIN_NO"` hard-coded into the path. Replace that with the user folder.

Comment: But I want the user folder to be dynamic as I have over 10 users. And I need them to store their files respectively to their ADMIN_NO

Comment: I've the following files in my File Explorer.

Courses is my main folder, followed by FAID_CSP and ADMIN_NO (which are sub folders).

Comment: Where do you get the user name that you want to use? I only see a hardcoded path and a filename here, not  any usernames.

Comment: `string filepath = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);` gives the extension of the file... `Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath);` will create directory with extenion of the file... why? where is the USER_ID value you are using? `Directory.CreateDirectory` should have the directory path with USER_ID value to create directory for userid. `postedfile.SaveAs` should also have USER_ID value to store file to userid specific folder.

Comment: Hi JonC. Currently, my username is stored in a database called Students.

Comment: @beepbeepdoola Then you need to fetch the username from the database before you try to save the files, otherwise you won't know what to name the folder.

Comment: Do you think using SQL would work? Currently, I've the following code where I retrieve information using SESSION. @JonC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile postedfile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
{
    string USER_ID = ????
    string userPath = Server.MapPath("Courses/FAID_CSP/ADMIN_NO/") + USER_ID;
    if (!Directory.Exists(userPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(userPath);
    }
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedfile.FileName);
    postedfile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(userPath, filename));
}
```

You have to provide a way to set USER_ID since you currently don't have that in your code.

Comment: Hmm, probably you made a point. Any idea of how can I set USER_ID in my codes?

Comment: It's impossible to say how to fetch a specific row from a database and map it to a file upload without knowing your entire application design. How do you keep track of who is uploading the files?

Comment: My entire application flow for this user (Student), is that they are logon to their respective account and upload their documents which will then be stored in a folder which is named after their USERID. For now, I will keep track by the folder names.

Comment: If you already have session entry from when the user logged on that has the ID that you want to use, why don't you use `string USER_ID = Session["id"];`

Answer (score 0):

Hi try the code below:

```
.......
//Get the admin number from somewhere.
int userId = GetAdminNo();
string subDir = $"Courses/FAID_CSP/{userId}/";
if (!Directory.Exists(subDir))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(subDir);
}

string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedfile.FileName);
postedfile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(subDir + filename));
......
```

Comment: Hello Gellio Gao. Thank you for helping. Do you have any idea of how can I get the admin number? Currently, it is all stored in a database called Student.